# How to improve Angular2 rendering performances when accessing a backend server?

Tags: performance, angular

I have a service which is responsible for getting the data from a backend.
The data is shown via a component in its nginit method. It is shown in a table (html table).

I would like to be able to manipulate data without having to reload it each time in my table : ex : delete a row, add a row ... I want all of this very fluid. The data is coming from a database.
So my question is : 
Should my service return an observable or an array ?
Is nginit the best place to show my table ?

How should I do things maybe to manage everything in memory? I do not know.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Please post the code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish, what you tried and where you failed.

Comment: There are no performance tips in general, especially on SO. There can only be performance tips to concrete problems. Therefore you're question should at least show what problem it is about, otherwise the question should be closed as too broad.

Comment: Hello, I decided to use Change Detection for performances. I prefer letting angular manage this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would save the data into an array then use lodash to manipulate it. 
You could edit, delete, and add rows using lodash's built in functions. When you want to save the data to the backend you would then post the array back to the server. This will keep backend requests to a minimum which will help your performance.

For example you could delete elements from the array using the remove function, https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#remove

Lodash can be setup like this https://medium.com/@gtsopour/importing-lodash-into-angular-2-typescript-application-94590365f46d#.9mdcdjnac

Of course you could do this all using raw js though but I find Lodash very rich and easy to use.